# AttributeError: module pyad has no attribute from_cn

Tags: python, active-directory

```
from pyad import *
import pyad.adquery


# Подключение к Active Directory
pyad.pyad_setdefaults(ldap_server="(***.***.***.***", username="", password="")

# Получение списка пользователей с указанным городом
ad_query = pyad.adquery.ADQuery()
ad_query.execute_query(
    attributes=["sAMAccountName", "l"],
    where_clause="l='Йемен'"
)
users = ad_query.get_results()

group = pyad.from_cn('mail.check')

# Очищаем существующих пользователей из группы
for member in group.get_members():
    group.remove(member)

# Добавляем новых пользователей в группу
for user in users:
    user_obj = pyad.from_cn(user["sAMAccountName"])
    group.add_members(user_obj)
```

Моя задача в пользователях в определенной директории по списку город сделать фильтрацию и добавить всех этих пользователей в группу рассылки. Авторизацию в AD хотелось бы сделать из под текущей сессии.
Но при попытке запустить код я получаю каждый раз введите сюда код
AttributeError: module pyad has no attribute from_cn
Так же пробовал меня на from_dn подскажите почему не выходит. Что делаю не так?